# Google Cloud Translate: cryptic error 400 invalid value

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I am using Google Translate (basic version) to translate some string. It was working fine a couple of minutes ago, but now it just returns error 400. The code is very simple:

```
function translatePhrase($text, $target, $source = 'it') {

    $sourceLanguage = $source;
    $targetLanguage = $target; 

    $translate = new TranslateClient();
    $result = $translate->translate($text, [
        'source' => $sourceLanguage,
        'target' => $targetLanguage,
    ]);

    $output = $result['text'];

    return $output;
}
```

It returns:

```
Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\BadRequestException: {
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid Value",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Invalid Value",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid"
}
]
}
}
in \vendor\google\cloud-core\src\RequestWrapper.php:362

Stack trace:
#0 \vendor\google\cloud-core\src\RequestWrapper.php(206): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException))
#1 \translate\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\RestTrait.php(95): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#2 \translate\vendor\google\cloud-translate\src\V2\Connection\Rest.php(83): Google\Cloud\Translate\V2\Connection\Rest->send('translations', 'translate', Array)
#3 \translate\vendor\google\cloud-translate\src\V2\TranslateClient.php(248): Google\Cloud\Translate\V2\Connection\Rest->listTra
in [\translate\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\RequestWrapper.php riga 362]
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason.

Basically, I was forcing a wrong source language. When I specified the correct source language it worked again.

Comment: One does not have to declare any source language, to begin with - and there might only be a few terms which exists in different languages, with a different meaning (as soon as it's a sentence, it should be no problem to use auto-detection).

Answer (score 0):

As one can see, it bugs out exactly [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-translate/blob/master/src/V2/TranslateClient.php#L248) ...so the options array is at fault. It should rather look alike this (because no single example passes a `source` language-code, but instead an auto-detected `$result['source']` is being returned):

```
function translatePhrase($text, $target) {
    $translate = new TranslateClient();
    $result = $translate->translate($text, [
        'target' => $target
    ]);
    return $result['text'];
}
```